# Is there a way to override the CSS of an "h6" tag within a link using the link's CSS?

Tags: css, overriding, hyperlink, nested

In a given container, I have a  bunch of links with another element inside it, like so:

```
<div class="container">
     <a href="whatever.com">
          <h6>Link Text Here</h6>
     </a>
</div>
```

And I have CSS which I want to use to format all links inside the "container" class:

```
.container a {
    color: #00f;
}
```

However, there are other external stylesheets which set the color of "h6" to something else.  Is there a way to make my CSS for links in the "container" override whatever someone else has put for "h6"?  I don't want to override all "h6" in the "container", because there are some "h6" tags which are *not* links.

Comment: Wouldn't `.container a h6 {...` work? Is your CSS loading before or after the other CSS?

Comment: You know this syntax (block elements within an `a` tag) is only valid in HTML5, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking you could use the !important to provide overriding.

```
   .container a h6
    {
       color: red !important;
    }
```

Comment: a combination of "!important" on the "a" tag and "inherit" on the "h6" tag did the trick  --thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.container a,
.container a h6 {
    color: #00f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are consistently using h6's in links, I would style the h6 elements nested in the A tag. The CSS would look like this:

```
.container a h6 {color:666;}
```

This is telling the CSS to look into the container class, find the link, and style only the h6 inside the a tag.

Comment: Couldnt there be color on an h6 tag already, and this would just be ignored? Thats why you need the !important?

Comment: Sure there could be, but you could avoid having to use the !important as long as you put the link h6 deceleration under the first h6 deceleration. I personally try to use !important as a last result

Answer (score 0):

I think, and I could be wrong, that you're looking for something like this:

```
.container a h6 {
    color: inherit;
}
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that whatever color you've given the containing `<a>` will cascade down to the h6 without having to explicitly set it. This way you only declare the color once. Easier maintainability and readability. Yay!

(This will work on IE8+)